# Integration with sympy

Tags: python, matlab, python-3.x, math, sympy

I'm trying to perform the following integration using `sympy`;

```
x = Symbol('x')
expr = (x+3)**5
integrate(expr)
```

The answer that I'm expecting is:

[image]

But what's being returned is:

[image]

The following code works in MATLAB:

```
syms x
y = (x+3)^5;
int(y)
```

I'm unsure what I'm doing wrong in order to perform this using `sympy`.

Comment: Furthermore, your Matlab integrand is different from your sympy integrand: `(x+3)^5` vs `(x+3)**6`.

Comment: @ajcr argh yes - I meant to put (x+3)^5 as the original expression I'm going to change now, thanks

Comment: I've edited the post with the correct inputs now

Comment: Have you tried expanding `(x+3)^6/6` to see if it's different?:)

Comment: This answer is simply correct. We always wrote "+ C" in indefinite integrals (and you could lose half a point for omitting it) at school. Next time you doubt it, paste the result into Matlab and integrate ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is actually a common problem seen in Calculus where for these kinds of polynomial expressions, you do get two answers.  The coefficients for each of the powers of `x` exist but the constant factor is missing between them.

As such, there are two methods you can use to find the indefinite integral of this expression.

1. The first method is to perform a substitution where `u = x+3`, then integrate with respect to `u`.  Then, the indefinite integral would be `(1/6)*(x + 3)^6 + C` as you expect.
2. The second method is to fully expand out the polynomial and integrate each term individually.

---

MATLAB elects to find the integral the first way:

```
>> syms x;
>> out = int((x+3)^5)

out =

(x + 3)^6/6
```

Something to note for later is that if we expand out this polynomial expression, we get:

```
>> expand(out)

ans =

x^6/6 + 3*x^5 + (45*x^4)/2 + 90*x^3 + (405*x^2)/2 + 243*x + 243/2
```

---

`sympy` elects to find the integral the second way:

```
In [20]: from sympy import *

In [21]: x = sym.Symbol('x')

In [22]: expr = (x+3)**5

In [23]: integrate(expr)
Out[23]: x**6/6 + 3*x**5 + 45*x**4/2 + 90*x**3 + 405*x**2/2 + 243*x
```

---

You'll notice that the answer is the same between both environments, but the constant factor is missing.  Because the constant factor is missing, there is no neat way to factor this into the neat polynomial that you are expecting from your output seen in MATLAB.

As a final note, if you would like to reproduce what `sympy` generates, expand out the polynomial, then integrate.  We get what `sympy` generates:

```
>> syms x;
>> out = expand((x+3)^5)

out =

x^5 + 15*x^4 + 90*x^3 + 270*x^2 + 405*x + 243

>> int(out)

ans =

x^6/6 + 3*x^5 + (45*x^4)/2 + 90*x^3 + (405*x^2)/2 + 243*x
```

The constant factor though shouldn't worry you.  In the end, what you are mostly concerned with is a **definite** integral, and so the subtraction of these constant factors will happen, which won't affect the final result.

---

## Side Note

Thanks to DSM, if you specify the `manual=True` flag for `integrate`, this will attempt to mimic performing integration by hand, which will give you the answer you're expecting:

```
In [26]: from sympy import *

In [27]: x = sym.Symbol('x')

In [28]: expr = (x+3)**5

In [29]: integrate(expr, manual=True)
Out[29]: (x + 3)**6/6
```

Comment: Note that `integrate((x+3)**5, manual=True)` tries some more, well, "manual" processes to find the antiderivative, and in this case produces the form of the output the OP is expecting.  As you say, though, it's more important to realize *why* the form doesn't matter.

Comment: @DSM I didn't know that.  As you can see, my exposure to `sympy` is quite limited.  Thank you for that note :).  I've also edited my post.  Thanks!

Comment: thats ace thanks - the `manual=True` works as I'd hope it to. There seem to be some things that I was unaware of, I've just discovered the `manualintegrate` thing as well. Thanks

Comment: @baxx As you can also tell, I'm not very familiar with `sympy` so `manualintegrate` is news for me too.  Thanks for the accept, you are most welcome and good luck!